# SQL - Find pairs and update + insert

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this

```
ID  |  map       |   status       |
===================================
1   |      1     |   searching    |
2   |      1     |   searching    |
3   |      2     |   searching    |
4   |      2     |   searching    |
5   |      1     |   searching    |
6   |      3     |   searching    |
```

I want to go trough the table and find pairs (only 2) where status is searching and they are having the same map. Then update their status and INSERT some information from the two rows into another table.

EDIT: The values in map are unknown. So i need to get them first and "iterate" to find pairs.

Comment: `select * from tablename  where status= "searching" GROUP BY map  limit 2;`

Comment: "Unclear What you are Asking. ??? "  again & again you change the Question !!   " Read How to Ask the Question "https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Limit 2 will also execute if there is only 1 entry..

Comment: Yes Is execute !! if there is only one data found !!

Comment: I dont want that...i want to find PAIRS only

Comment: `select * from tablename where status="searching" and map="id_of_paris" GROUP BY map limit 2;`

Comment: How do you identify which two?  there are 3 there with status Searching and the same map?  what should the results be for your sample dataset

Comment: Sorted by ID.. So always the first two. If there is no pair then do nothing.

Comment: what if there are 4 with the same mapping?  Are they two pairs or do you only care about the first pair?

Comment: Yes! Two pairs! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will pair each ID with the next matching ID;  if there are more than 2 you will get some overlap.

```
Select * from 
    TableName as t1 
    inner join 
    TableName as t2 
on 
    t1.status= 'searching' 
and t2.status = 'searching' 
and t1.map=t2.map  
and t1.id<t2.id
```

Comment: updated to put tablename instead of table to make it clearer (and correct).  This is a self-join, you join the table to itself.